How to receive Push Notifications from NextPush (UnifiedPush Provider) on Linux?
I’m looking for a way to create an app or simple script on Linux that can receive push notifications from a UnifiedPush provider, specifically NextPush from a Nextcloud instance. Ideally, it should work across different Linux desktop environments (GNOME, KDE, etc.). How can I achieve this?
